# position small span element below title span

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I have the layout with the code below, where each list item has a title "Item 0", below there is a small tag with text "Description Item 0" and then two select menus at right. I want the layout as it is, the only issue is that I want the small tag "Description Item 0" below the title "Item 0" but its not working. With a `<br>` is not working because the title and the small are different span elements. Do you know how to put the small tag below the title "Item 0" and maitain the vertically alignment of elements?

example: https://jsfiddle.net/uxvh0gmj/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <span class="title">Item 0</span>
              <br>
              <span><small>Description Item 0</small></span>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="button" class="float-right btn">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.title{
  color:gray;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the HTML, or only the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap them in the same `div` and keep the `br` to create the line break:

```css
.title {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div>
                <span class="title">Item 0</span>
                <br>
                <small>Description Item 0</small>
              </div>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="button" class="float-right btn">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain, why the br tag takes place only if the whole thing is wrapped in a div?

Comment: @Legends because of the flex .. inside the div, no flex layout so the br work normally and outside we have a flex layout and br is flex child and the default direction of flex i row, so all the child will stay at the same line

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: i didn't removed or add anything, I just switched their places

If you insert the span inside the other span, it will go next to it, but it you add a `<br>` between then it will place it under it.

Here's the edited code:

```
 <div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <span class="title">Item 0<br><span>Description Item 0</span></span>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="button" class="float-right btn">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The changes I made was:

```
<span class="title">Item 0<br><span>Description Item 0</span></span>
```

You can add this CSS code to prevent the description span to look like the title

```
.description {
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

and then just add `class="description"` to the second span.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them in the same `div` or same `span`

```css
.title {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <span>
                <span class="title">Item 0</span>
                <br>
                <small>Description Item 0</small>
              </span>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control" style="width:100px;">                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="button" class="float-right btn">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```